# Geospatial 2dsphere index not creating in MongoDB Atlas and manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, geospatial, geojson

I am trying to create a `2sphere` index in my mongodb collection. The index needs to be on `location` field which is at GeoJSON format:

```
location: {    
   coordinates: [lat, long],
   type: "Point" 
}
```

My manual query in JS:

`db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).createIndex({ "location": "2dsphere" });`

When I create the index in Mongo Atlas, it appears and disappears after a few seconds on the screen.

An error is occuring when creating the index but I don't know what.

My `$near` query:

```
db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
      .find({
        location: {
          $near: {
            $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lng, lat] },
            $minDistance: 1000,
            $maxDistance: 5000,
          },
        },
      })
```

Error:

`planner returned error :: caused by :: unable to find index for $geoNear query`
This error is because my index is not creating.

Hope people out there can help! :) Thanks a lot!

Documentation used: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoJSON coords are `long,lat` not `lat,long`.   It is very likely that you have some bad data in your `location` field and this is preventing the index from being created correctly.  If even one doc in a collection of 1000 has bad geo data, the index will not be created. To test, if you can, drop the data from the collection, create the `2dsphere` index, then in a loop add the data back and watch the return code from `insert`.  Bad GeoJSON data will cause an error on insert, allowing you to mark these items as needing attention but permitting the majority to insert with index support.

Comment: Alright thanks, so basically mongo indexing is sensitive to the ordering of the coordinates?

Comment: You were right it works with `long,lat` and not the opposite!! Thank you so much! Mongo should integrate an error message though, even generic would be helpful

Comment: More than index sensitivity, it is a data domain issue.  long is -180 to 180 and lat is -90 to 90.   If you have a (long,lat) coord like `[-110,40]` and you swap the values to  `[40,-110]` that produces an out-of-domain error for latitude.   And: don't be afraid to click the checkbox as the accepted answer.   ;-)